# Sed with python and many parameters

Tags: python, sed, replace

I have a big file with some lines like:

### Users.txt

- User1:jhonny
- User2:Mary
- User3:Jane

And another file with:

### Data.txt

- User1:Brown
- User3:Yellow
- User2:Green

I want to make just one file, replacing the first field of Data.txt with the second field in Users.txt.
On the final, it may look like this:

### Final.txt

- Jhonny:Brown
- Jane:Yellow
- Mary:Green

I have made the following code in python.

```
with open("File", "r") as sources:
    lines = sources.readlines()
with open("File", "w") as sources:
    for line in lines:
        sources.write(re.sub(r'TextToReplace', 'ParameterToReplace', line))
```

I need to replace TextToReplace with the first field on the file Users.txt and the ParameterToReplace is the second field on Users.txt. Many times, with 30M+ parameters.

It's like a command `sed 's/TextToReplace/ParameterToReplace/" File`

- TextToReplace = The old text to be replaced.
- ParameterToReplace = The new text.

Comment: Is the data in the files sorted? Will it always be `User1:, User2` etc?

Comment: Also your python attempt isn't even an attempt -- it looks like you just grabbed any code off the internet and pasted it into the question

Comment: The data on Users.txt  is sorted. I sorted with Sort command on bash.
But the data on Data.txt Isn't sorted.

Comment: Yes, i grabbed and modified, it's a Sed alternative. If it fits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use dict if data has mixed:

```
userdict={}
for i in open("users.txt","r").read().split("\n"):
    arr=i.split(":")
    userdict[arr[0]]=arr[1]
with open("final.txt","w") as f:
    for i in open("data.txt","r").read().split("\n"):
        arr=i.split(":")
        f.write("{}:{}".format(userdict[arr[0]],arr[1]))
```

Comment: than data file not like youre saying

Answer (score 0):

The [`join` command](https://manpage.me/?q=join) is useful for this kind of thing.
Assuming your shell understands [Process Substitutions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
$ join -o 1.2,2.2 -t: <(sort users.txt) <(sort data.txt)
jhonny:Brown
Mary:Green
Jane:Yellow
```